# How do I quit Apple Music?

Tags: music, apple-music

So recently I started listening to Apple Music, but I didn’t realise that I had to pay 10 dollars every month. Now I want to quit it.

Anyways, I tried going to my account, but there wasn’t a button to stop using Apple Music.

Should I delete the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Open the Music app, then tap For You.
> 2. Tap the profile icon <sub>[image]</sub> or your photo in the upper-right corner.
> 3. Scroll to the bottom of your profile page and tap View Account. If you haven't set up an Apple Music profile, skip to step 4.
> 4. Tap View Apple ID. You might be asked to authenticate your Apple ID.
> 5. Scroll to Subscriptions and tap it, then tap Apple Music. If you don't have any other subscriptions, you'll go straight to Apple Music.
> 6. Tap Cancel Subscription, then tap Confirm. After you cancel, your subscription will stop at the end of the current billing cycle.

[Manage your Apple Music subscription on your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, Mac, PC, or Apple TV](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204939)

Answer (score 0):

You should ask Google as I did for you ))
It depends on your device.
Here is the full topic with an answer (I think):
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204939#autorenew